# Error after upgrading Joomla 3.1.5 to 3.2.3 - what's the proper method?

Tags: joomla, upgrade

I've tried every method I can think of to update from 3.1.5 to 3.2.3 and each time it pretty much kills my site and leaves me with the error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method JLoader::registerAlias() in /homepages/.../libraries/cms.php on line 61

At which point I just clobber the rest of the site and reinstall my backup (oh man you GOTTA LOVE Akeeba).

I've upgraded Joomla successfully and unsuccessfully about 100 times over the past few years on various sites and this is the first time I'm stumped as how to move forward.

One interesting piece of data is in the Admin Control Panel of the 3.1.5 is that the Joomla version says "Unknown" even though the System Information lists it as 3.1.5.

So, anyway, what is the ABSOLUTE, BLESSED method for moving from 3.1.5 to 3.2.3? If I should simply be able to install the 3.2.3 upgrade zip file then I guess I'm toast. In that case, what would happen if I left the database as is and cleared out all the files and then installed the 3.2.3 full stable package? Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Akeeba backup installed? You need to make sure it is updated first before updating joomla.
So if yo have a back up, restore that, update Akeeba, then update Joomla again.
http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/general-discussion/215394-pressing-the-joomla-update-button-killed-my-site

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty easy, though unexpected.  See [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=710&t=839546).